# how to use iOS 12 simulator in Xcode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode12

I want to use a simulator with iOS 12 in Xcode to build, run and test my app. I did some searching and installed iOS 12 from Xcode -> Preferences -> Components. [image]

but in simulator list, I only have access to iOS 14 simulators.

[image]

when I select Add Additional simulators, I can see simulators with iOS 12 equipped:

[image]

but I can't tell Xcode to use them. any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set iOS deployment target to 12.0